# Delete recipient with Rest API in Java

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to delete a specific recipient from an envelope. I wrote a little Java program and tried various DELETE requests, but I always get an error back:

```
<errorCode>INVALID_REQUEST_BODY</errorCode>
  <message>The request body is missing or improperly formatted. <signers xmlns=''> was not expected.</message>
```

I tried with this request:

```
baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/recipients/"+recipientId;
and no body
```

as well as:

```
baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/recipients/"
with body="<recipients xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\"><agents><agent><recipientId>"+recipientId+"</recipientId></agent></agents></recipients>";
```

Both without success.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referring to the DocuSign REST documentation regarding deleting recipients?

https://www.docusign.com.au/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Delete Recipients from an Envelope.htm?Highlight=delete recipient